# Extra slash after domain required after removing 'index.php' from Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying to remove the 'index.php' from my Codeigniter site using mod-rewrite. However I end up with this problem:

Original URI:
http://mysite.com/index.php/about

Only way to make it work *after* removing index.php:
http://mysite.com//about (note the extra slash)

Removing the extra slash causes Codeigniter to not 'see' the url string after the domain.

I've tried 3 different mod-rewrite methods now and all end up with the same problem - URIs don't work unless you add an extra slash **after** the domain name.

My current mod_rewrite code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co
RewriteRule (.*) http://domainname.co/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: please post the mod_rewrite code you are using, to make sure its correct.

Second: check in your application config file that your the index page is set to nothing like this `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: Thanks, updated with current mod_rewrite code. Also tried a much simpler variant on the Codeigniter forum - same problem. RE:$config['index_page'] - I've tried 'index.php' 'index.php/' '' and ' '. Documentation suggests removing it if you're using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is quite simple.

Edit your `.htaccess` like this -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /<directory_where_your_code_is_kept>/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co
RewriteRule (.*) http://domainname.co/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Then goto `config.php` and make these changes -

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/<directory_where_your_code_is_kept>';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's still not working. Where you put "RewriteBase /<directory_where_your_code_is_kept>/" Should that be "RewriteBase /" or "RewriteBase //"? (my code is in the site's top directory)

Comment: No `//`. Only one single `/`. And if it's in the top directory, just leave leave it as `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: Okay, well that's exactly as it was. RE: Your other suggested changes, the only thing different to my original config was 'uri_protocol' was AUTO instead of REQUEST_URI. Any other ideas what might be causing this issue? Thanks.

Comment: The changes which are supposed to be made are - 1. `.htaccess` 2. changes in `config.php`

Comment: @Zaph Are you on a Linux environment or running it via Wamp. If you are running on Linux, then you need to edit your apache.conf and make `AllowOverride All` for your directory.